# Execute a function n times, where n is known at compile time

Tags: haskell, template-meta-programming

## Motivation

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42179783/is-there-any-way-to-inline-a-recursive-function), a user asked whether it is possible to inline the following function:

```
-- simplified version
{-# INLINE nTimes #-}
nTimes :: Int -> (a -> a) -> a -> a    
nTimes 0 f x = x
nTimes n f x = nTimes (n-1) f (f x)
```

Unfortunately, the answer seems no, since GHC sees a recursive function and gives up. Even if you use a compile-time constant, e.g. `nTimes 1 (+1) x`, you don't end up with `x + 1`, but with `nTimes 1 (+1) x`.

While it's of course fine to refuse inlining if the number of loops is unknown, it's also a hassle if it *is* known.

## Code

As you can see in the question above, I've proposed the following solution:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
module Times where

import Control.Monad (when)
import Language.Haskell.TH

-- > item under review begins here

nTimesTH :: Int -> Q Exp
nTimesTH n = do
  f <- newName "f"
  x <- newName "x"

  when (n <= 0)    (reportWarning "nTimesTH: argument non-positive")
  when (n >= 1000) (reportWarning "nTimesTH: argument large, can lead to memory exhaustion")

  let go k | k <= 0 = VarE x
      go k          = AppE (VarE f) (go (k - 1))
  return $ LamE [VarP f,VarP x] (go n)

-- < item under review ends here
```

This should, for any `n`, create a function with patterns named `f` and `x`, and apply `f` to `x` with `AppE` `n` times:

```
$(nTimesTH 0) = \f x -> x
$(nTimesTH 1) = \f x -> f x
$(nTimesTH 2) = \f x -> f (f x)
$(nTimesTH 3) = \f x -> f (f (f x))
```

I can verify that the created function has the correct type:

```
$ ghci -XTemplateHaskell Times.sh 
ghci> :t $(nTimesTH 0)
$(nTimesTH 0) :: r -> r1 -> r1

ghci> :t $(nTimesTH 1)
$(nTimesTH 1) :: (r1 -> r) -> r1 -> r

ghci> :t $(nTimesTH 2)
$(nTimesTH 2) :: (r -> r) -> r -> r

ghci> :t $(nTimesTH 3)
$(nTimesTH 3) :: (r -> r) -> r -> r
```

To all my knowledge, `nTimesTH` works exactly as expected.

Given that this is my first time dabbling with Template Haskell, does this follow best practices? Also, I'm using `VarE`, `AppE` and so on. `Language.Haskell.TH` also provides some combinators, so that one can write

```
  let go k | k <= 0 = varE x
      go k          = appE (varE f) (go (k - 1))
  lamE (map varP [f,x]) (go n)
```

Is this just personal preference, or is `lamE` preferred? As far as I can see, the expression combinators use the canonic implementation, e.g. `varE = return . VarE`, `appE f x = liftA2 AppE f x` and so on.

## Tests

Just for completeness the QuickCheck tests. Those aren't really part of the review, but here fore completeness:

```
module Times where
import Test.QuickCheck

-- .. rest of module as above

genTestSingle :: Int -> Q Exp
genTestSingle n = do
  f <- newName "gTSf"
  x <- newName "gTSx"

  lamE [varP f, varP x] $ 
    appsE [ [| (==) |], appsE [nTimesTH n,           varE f, varE x]
                      , appsE [ [| nTimesFoldr n |], varE f, varE x]]

genAllTest :: Int -> Q Exp
genAllTest n = do
  f <- newName "gATf"
  x <- newName "gATv"

  lamE [varP f, varP x] $ doE $ (flip map) [1..n] $ \i ->
    noBindS $ appE [| quickCheck |] $ appsE [genTestSingle i, varE f, varE x]
```

```
module Main where

main = $(genAllTest 100) sin 40
```

Comment: Note: Please ___don't use `nTimesTH n f x` with large values `n`, if `f` isn't inlineable or `x` isn't also a compile-time constant.___  This **will** eat all your RAM.

Comment: `go n` is `iterate (AppE (VarE f)) (VarE x) !! max 0 n`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your implementation is fine. But it is a little bit ironic: In your SO answer, you start of with *"you can use better functions"*, yet you rewrite `nTimes` via `go`. If this was a real module, you would probably want to export both functions `nTimesTH` and `nTimes`, and implement the former via the latter:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
module Times (nTimes, nTimesTH) where

import Control.Monad (when)
import Language.Haskell.TH

-- example implementation
nTimes :: Int -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
nTimes n f x = iterate f x !! max 0 n

nTimesTH :: Int -> Q Exp
nTimesTH n = do
  when (n <= 0)    (reportWarning "nTimesTH: argument non-positive")
  when (n >= 1000) (reportWarning "nTimesTH: argument large, can lead to memory exhaustion")

  f <- newName "f"
  x <- newName "x"

  lamE (map varP [f,x]) $ nTimes n (appE (varE f)) (varE x)
```

This removes the need for code duplication, and any future optimization you find for `nTimes` gets automatically applied in `nTimesTH`, although that only matter during the compile time. After all `$(nTimesTH n)` is completely evaluated during compilation.

Other than that, I moved the warnings on top of the function, since this brings the names `f` and `x` closer to their actual use. I also replaced the data constructors with their respective functions.

Note that for a real module you still want to add documentation:

```
-- | @'nTimes' n f x@ applies @f@ @n@ times over @x@. 
-- It does not apply @f@ if @n@ is negative. In this case @x@ is returned.
--
-- prop> nTimes n f x == iterate f x !! max 0
nTimes :: Int -> (a -> a) -> a -> a

-- | @'nTimesTH' n@ returns a function that applies the first 
--   argument @n@ times to the second argument. 
--   @n@ must be known at compile time. Needs @-XTemplateHaskell@.
--
-- prop> $(nTimesTH n) f x == nTimes n f x
nTimesTH :: Int -> Q Exp
```